# Qt Eclipse integration. Now always makes debug and release versions

Tags: qt, eclipse-cdt

The C++ program I am writing under Linux (OpenSuse) had a bug in it where it consumed all available RAM including page memory. This affected badly the system and all programs it was running. More importantly eclipse (amongst other programs) was unable to close properly and I eventually had to power off the machine.
After powering the machine back up again and restarting eclipse all seemed well except when compiling under eclipse it now compiles both the debug and release versions whenever I press Control-B, my usual short cut.
So the question is how do I recover from this situation whereby I had a debug and release version of the program and Control-B would compile either the debug or release version but not both. I see this as an inconvenience but as the program gets larger the compile times are getting longer (twice as long as necessary) and I can only drink so much tea whilst I wait.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.
The Control-B short cut does a 'Build All' and so the answer is 'As Designed'.
But this begs two other questions.
Firstly I am sure that previously the Control-B short cut only compiled the Debug version. So I have no idea how I got eclipse to do that. That was something I did a long time ago.
Secondly how do I get just a Debug or a Release build but not both. I cannot discover an option for this. On my setup the 'Build Project' option still invokes both Debug and Release builds.